# Populate ng-options after ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using the latest stable AngularJS (1.3.15), populating the `ng-options` of a `<select>` *after* the `ng-model` was already populated, it appears that the model is not selected.

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Selected: {{selected}}
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item as item for item in list">
      <option value="">-- Select something --</option>
    </select>
    <span ng-show="loading">(loading...)</span>
  </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.selected = 'first';
  $scope.list = [];
  $scope.loading = true;
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.list = ["first","second","third"];
    $scope.loading = false;
  }, 1000);
});
```

[Or Plunker with both.](http://plnkr.co/edit/EhYzHols7DzwLmZ6EF2h?p=preview)

If the `list` is populated using a `$timeout()` to simulate lazy loading, the `<option>` elements are updated, but the value in `ng-model` is not selected (I would expect the value `first` to be selected). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ng-options="item for item in list track by $index"` then set value of selected in after ajax load `$scope.selected = first`

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Selected: {{selected}}
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item for item in list track by $index">
    </select>
    <span ng-show="loading">(loading...)</span>
  </body>
```

**Note**

> Using tack by $index will fix your problem, though [**select is not
>   compatible with select**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564)

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LYgycS5XgUzQQtlhBhWQ?p=preview)

Comment: It seems that adding any `track by` works. So this looks like a bug in Angular, do you agree?

Comment: @stackular yes you can say that..though it is not fully compatible with select here is issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564

Answer (score 0):

**Dimi Toulakis** and **pankajparkar** are right, you need to set the selected item when your list change.

But if you ask **why** :

It is intentional, if after each change in the list, the first item is selected, then this would not be comprehensive for the user.

**Ex:** I have a list `[1,2,3,4]`

Let's say I (an user) select 2, then an ajax call update the list (which is now `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`), it would be very strange if it changed the selected item. The user would not understand what happened, and he would send a form with a bad selected value.